# how to update delta table from dataframe in pyspark without merge

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

IN SQL, it is possible to perform an update of a table based on data from another table

```
UPDATE        scores
SET           scores.name = p.name
FROM          scores s
INNER JOIN    people p
ON            s.personId = p.id
```

In PySpark (in conjunction with Delta Tables), I currently do see only the `merge` [command](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/python/index.html#delta.tables.DeltaTable.merge), that could deliver a similar pattern.

```
deltaTable.alias("s").merge(
    source = people.alias("p"),
    condition = "s.personId = p.id"
  ).whenMatchedUpdate(set =
    {
      "name": "p.name"
    }
  ).execute()
```

But referring to [this](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2020/09/29/diving-into-delta-lake-dml-internals-update-delete-merge.html) blog, there is an overhead of performing a merge instead of an update operation (more necessary joins). Is it possible to use the `update` command instead in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to use MERGE instead. Even if there was such possibility, additional joins would be still required - data files in Delta aren't updated in place, so Spark first need to figure out which files will be affected by update, then extract all rows that need to be updated and update them, and write them into a new file together with not affected rows.